# my get_viewport().get_mouse_position() isn't working right godot GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make a 2d platformer where you spawn an object and try to jump on it in the air before it falls.

the problem is when I try to spawn the tile it doesn't spawn where Is the cursor at
it adds a relative value to the position that I don't know how to get rid of it.

you see when I try to instance a scene it takes the cursor position and viewport value into account but then something happens and I fount the object spawning way too far.

[see where is the cursor at and where did the tile spawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e5YR.png)

[, same thing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcjD2.png)

[, and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZYnU.png)

[-here is how I'm grouping the nodes and scenes-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpkbX.png)

and this is the script I'm using, it's in the player1 scene

```
extends KinematicBody2D
# 
var score : int = 0

export var speed : int = 200
export var jumpforce : int = 600
export var gravity : int = 800

onready var AB1 = preload("res://player1AB.tscn")

var vel :Vector2 = Vector2()

onready var sprite : Sprite = get_node("sprite_idile")
onready var ui : Node = get_node("/root/mainscene1/CanvasLayer/ui")
onready var audioplayer : Node = get_node("/root/mainscene1/Camera2D/audio_player")

func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = 0
    # movement inputs
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        vel.x -= speed

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        vel.x += speed

    # applying the velcoty
    vel = move_and_slide(vel,Vector2.UP)

    #apllying gravty
    vel.y += gravity * delta

    #jump input
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y -= jumpforce

    # where the sprite facing
        if vel.x < 0:
        sprite.flip_h = true
    if vel.x > 0:
        sprite.flip_h = false

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("restart"):
        death()



func death ():
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()



func collect_coin (value):
    score += value
    ui.set_score_text(score)
    audioplayer.play_coin_sfx()


func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("click"):
        var ABT1 = AB1.instance()
        add_child(ABT1)
        var XN = null
        XN = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()  
        ABT1.position = XN
```

---

important stuff

```
onready var AB1 = preload("res://player1AB.tscn")



func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("click"):
        var ABT1 = AB1.instance()
        add_child(ABT1)
        var XN = null
        XN = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()  
        ABT1.position = XN
```

this the same problem in Godot form check it out if possible in case someone answered there

https://godotforums.org/discussion/27007/my-get-viewport-get-mouse-position-isnt-working-right#latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### If you don't have an extra Viewport

My first intuition is to get `get_global_mouse_position` and set `global_position`. That way you don't have to deal with any relative positioning:

```
    ABT1.global_position = get_global_mouse_position()
```

---

Alternatively, you can check if the event is `InputEventMouse`, make it local with `make_input_local`, and get `InputEventMouse.position` from it:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouse and event.is_action_pressed("click"):

        var ABT1 = AB1.instance()
        add_child(ABT1)

        event = make_input_local(event)
        ABT1.position = event.position
```

This approach would make it easier to then add touch support, because it does not rely on any function that gives you the mouse position. See my answer for [Holding screen touch in godot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467045/402022).

---

### If you have an extra Viewport

First of all, make sure you put your `Viewport` inside a `ViewportContainer` (otherwise it does not get input, see [_input not called for a node inside a Viewport](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/194707/10408)). Then we can use that `ViewportContainer` to get our coordinates.

Something like this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouse and event.is_action_pressed("click"):

        var ABT1 = AB1.instance()
        add_child(ABT1)

        var container = find_parent("ViewportContainer") as ViewportContainer
        if container != null:
            event = container.make_input_local(event)

        event = make_input_local(event)
        ABT1.position = event.position
```

Notice there I'm using the function `find_parent`. It matches by `name` of the `Node`, not by type. Another approach you can try is using `get_viewport().get_parent()`.

*And yes, that should work regardless of stretch mode.*

Comment: man thank you really you didn't only help me fix this problem also helped fix a problem in the future when I want to port it to mobile.
Can I ask you? Where did get this much information about programming or did you accumulate it over time?

Comment: @mhmoodalem Accumulated over time. Yet I'm not entirely self-thought either. I studied engineering, and that instills a problem solving approach, which I apply here. If you have a problem, make a project just for that problem. Do some research, which can be in reading documentation/examples/source code, good old experimentation, or asking people. Then you do prototyping and testing based on that. Repeat as needed. If you find a solution, you can incorporate it in whatever it is you are building. If you don't find it, judgement call: keep trying or workaround it. Learning happens on the way.

Comment: This solution still works for me as of Godot 4.2