# rotation of character by finger

Tags: godot, gdscript

Task is to make a rotation of character around its vertical axis. as input we want to use a round motion by finger at any place of screen. we tried to use two methods firts by using ray but then you need to drag finger around character ( working but not like we need )

```
func _process(_delta):
    look_at_cursor()

func look_at_cursor():
    var player_position = global_transform.origin
    var drop_plane = Plane(Vector3(0, 1, 0), player_position.y)
    var mouse_position = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    var ray_length  = 1000
    var ray_start = $Position3D/Camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
    var end_ray = ray_start + $Position3D/Camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_position) * ray_length
    var cursor_pos = drop_plane.intersects_ray(ray_start, end_ray)
    look_at(cursor_pos, Vector3.UP)
    shoot_point = end_ray
```

and second one is with InputEventScreenDrag, its working but only in one direction. help here plz.

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventScreenDrag:
            var rotx = event.relative.x * rot_speed 
            var roty = event.relative.y * rot_speed
            #if rotx < 0:
            #    rotx = - rotx
            #if roty < 0:
            #    roty = - roty
            #rotate_y(rotx+roty)
```

Comment: You are making sure your variables are positive (`if rotx < 0: rotx = - rotx` and `if roty < 0: roty = - roty`) so `rotx+roty` is always positive, and thus `rotate_y(rotx+roty)` is always a positive rotation. I don't know how you want it to behave, but if the problem is that `its working but only in one direction`, well, don't do that.

Comment: that scratch should be removed, and if we do so then char rotates from -90 to +90, the task to make a rotation 360 degrees.

Comment: It will rotate the full turn if you drag in a straight line (I wanted to test to make sure). But you want to drag in a circle, right?

Comment: Yes you're right. Received you answer many thanks, will test it and write here how is it going.

Comment: Thank you much, working pretty good, add only one thing.                                            
 if relative != last_relative:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This took me a while to figure out between testing and solving some jitter problem… I'll explain.*

First of all, I decided to start with the technique I describe in [Holding screen touch in godot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68466284/402022). So the start of my `_input` looks like this:

```
func _input(event:InputEvent):
    if not event is InputEventMouse\
      and not event is InputEventScreenDrag\
      and not event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        return

    var is_left_click:bool = event is InputEventMouse\
      and ((event as InputEventMouse).button_mask & BUTTON_LEFT) != 0
    var is_drag := event is InputEventScreenDrag\
      or (event is InputEventMouseMotion and is_left_click)
```

---

And for the rotation, I decided to use the concept of [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)). And by that I mean, I'll be using the cross product to figure out in what direction to rotate. This way we don't need to define a center of rotation (so you can do circles in any part of the screen and it should still work).

Let us declare `curl`:

```
var curl:float = 0.0
```

And since we will be doing cross product, we need to hold the last relative, so we can do a cross product with the current one. So declare `last_relative`:

```
var last_relative:Vector3 = Vector3.ZERO
```

And let us do the cross product:

```
    var relative := Vector3(event.relative.x, event.relative.y, 0).normalized()
    curl = relative.cross(last_relative).z
    last_relative = relative
```

However, we need to make sure to reset that for the next drag. We will set it when `is_drag` is false (that is on press and on release):

```
    if is_drag:
        var relative := Vector3(event.relative.x, event.relative.y, 0).normalized()
        curl = relative.cross(last_relative).z
        last_relative = relative
    else:
        last_relative = Vector3.ZERO
        curl = 0.0
```

---

Next issue on the table is rotation speed. I ended up using `_physics_process`. Which also allows us to use `delta`, so that rotation speed is stable.

Speaking of rotation speed, declare `rot_speed`:

```
var rot_speed:float = TAU
```

*`TAU` means one rotation per second.*

And now we can write `_physics_process`:

```
func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    rotate_y(sign(curl) * rot_speed * delta)
```

---

Next up is jitter. One part of it was input emulation. So I disabled it. But that was not enough. To fully solve jitter, `_input` will not write `curl`, but `target_curl` instead.

First declare `target_curl`:

```
var target_curl:float = 0.0
```

And then set it in `_input`:

```
    if is_drag:
        var relative := Vector3(event.relative.x, event.relative.y, 0).normalized()
        target_curl = relative.cross(last_relative).z
        last_relative = relative
    else:
        last_relative = Vector3.ZERO
        target_curl = 0.0
```

Now, we will ease `curl` into `target_curl` in `physics_process`:

```
func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    if target_curl > curl:
        curl += delta
        if curl > target_curl:
            curl = target_curl
    elif target_curl < curl:
        curl -= delta
        if curl < target_curl:
            curl = target_curl

    rotate_y(sign(curl) * rot_speed * delta)
```

---

Finally, when the user is holding position (not dragging), we don't get any `_input`. Which means the user can do a little arc, and hold position, and the physics body would continue to rotate. We solve that by erasing `target_curl` every physics frame.

Complete code listing:

```
extends KinematicBody

var rot_speed:float = TAU
var last_relative:Vector3 = Vector3.ZERO
var curl:float = 0.0
var target_curl:float = 0.0

func _input(event:InputEvent):
    if not event is InputEventMouse\
      and not event is InputEventScreenDrag\
      and not event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        return

    var is_left_click:bool = event is InputEventMouse\
      and ((event as InputEventMouse).button_mask & BUTTON_LEFT) != 0
    var is_drag := event is InputEventScreenDrag\
      or (event is InputEventMouseMotion and is_left_click)

    if is_drag:
        var relative := Vector3(event.relative.x, event.relative.y, 0).normalized()
        target_curl = relative.cross(last_relative).z
        last_relative = relative
    else:
        last_relative = Vector3.ZERO
        target_curl = 0.0

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    if target_curl > curl:
        curl += delta
        if curl > target_curl:
            curl = target_curl
    elif target_curl < curl:
        curl -= delta
        if curl < target_curl:
            curl = target_curl

    rotate_y(sign(curl) * rot_speed * delta)
    target_curl = 0.0
```

*Tested on Windows with mouse, and on Android with touch.*