# Detect Hold Time in Touchscreen Godot

Tags: godot

I have touchscreen for my game so I am using InputEventScreenTouch function in my code.
I have Collisionpolygon2D area in my game and I add the inputevent signal which name is
_on20Pointsinput_event for this area. I need to detect this area I want to detect that this area is pressed for 2 seconds. How can I do this ?
I detect pressed with below function but how can I detect the holding ?

```
func _on_20_Points_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if (event is InputEventScreenTouch && event.pressed ):  # I want to detect press hold in 2 sec. How can I do this ?
```

I am trying like this but I think this is not good way to do :

```
func _on_20_Points_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if (event is InputEventScreenTouch && event.pressed):
        print("Here")
        print(event.position)
        if get_event_position == event.position:
            print("After timer:",event.position)
            GlobalVar.points += 20
            refresh_points()
            ani.play("Points_added")
            position_list.append(get_event_position)
            my_timer.stop()
        else:
            if !(event.position in position_list):  
                get_event_position = event.position
                print("before timer:", get_event_position)
                my_timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_20_Points_input_event",[viewport, event, shape_idx])
                my_timer.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Holding screen touch in godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466284/holding-screen-touch-in-godot)

Comment: No. this is not related. Because I'm trying to detect touch in screen but this is the mouse click position

Comment: s. If the touch position is change than inputevent working but if there is same point I dont have any trigger to test. How can I manage this ?